# Dirichlet characters mod $q$ of conductor $f_\chi|d|q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, characters

Let $\hat{G}_q$ be the set of Dirichlet characters modulo $q$. If $d|q$, how many $\chi\in\hat{G}_q$ are there with $f_\chi|d$? ($f_\chi$ denotes the conductor of $\chi$)

And what if we count the $\chi\in\hat{G}_q$ with $f_\chi|d$ and $\chi(-1)=\pm1$? I expect the number to be $\frac12\phi(d)$ but don't know how to prove that.

Thanks alot!

Comment: The characters modulo $q$ with conductor dividing $d$ form a group isomorphic to $({\mathbb Z}/d{\mathbb Z})^\times$, hence there are $\phi(d)$ of them.

Comment: Okay, but what's the isomorphism? I thougt of $\hat{G}_q\longrightarrow\{\text{primitive Dirichlet characters with conductor dividing }d\}$, $\chi\mapsto\chi'$ where $\chi'$ is the Drichlet character modulo $f_\chi$ that induces $\chi$. This map is one-to-one, but why is it onto?

Comment: There is a mistake in my above comment. I meant the mapping $\varphi_q:\{\chi\in\hat{G}_q:f_\chi|d\}\longrightarrow\{\text{primitive Dirichlet characters with conductor dividing }d\}$, $\chi\mapsto\chi'$ the Dirichlet character modulo $f_\chi$ that induces $\chi$. As I said it is one-to-one. As the codomain of $\varphi_q$ is isomorphic to $\hat{G}_d$ it is sufficient to prove that $\varphi_q$ is onto.

Comment: So let $\tilde{\chi}$ modulo $f$ be primitive, $f|d$. Thus, if $\varphi_q(\chi)=\tilde{\chi}$, $\chi$ is uniquely determined by $\chi(n)=\tilde{\chi}(n)$ for all $(n,q)=1$. But how prove $f_\chi|d$ and $\chi'(n)=\tilde{\chi}(n)$ for all $(n,q)>1$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, maybe I got it by myself: Let us define $\hat{P}_{d,\pm}:=\{\text{primitive Dirichlet characters $\tilde{\chi}$ with conductor dividing }d\text{ and }\tilde{\chi}(-1)=\pm1\}$ and $\hat{G}_{d,\pm}=\{\chi\in\hat{G}_q:f_\chi|d\text{ and }\chi(-1)=\pm1\}$. Let $\varphi:\hat{G}_{d,\pm}\longrightarrow \hat{P}_{d,\pm}$, $\chi\mapsto\chi'$, $\chi'$ the primitive character inducing $\chi$.

If $\tilde{\chi}\in\hat{P}_{d,\pm}$, set $\chi(n)=\tilde{\chi}(n)$ for all $(n,q)=1$ and $0$ otherwise. Thus, $\chi\in\hat{G}_q$ and $\tilde{\chi}$ induces $\chi$. So $\varphi(\chi)=\chi'$ and $\tilde{\chi}$ both are primitive inducing $\chi$, therefore $\varphi(\chi)=\tilde{\chi}$. But as $f_\chi=f_{\chi'}=f_{\tilde{\chi}}$ and $\chi(-1)=\chi(q-1)=\tilde{\chi}(q-1)=\pm1$ we got $\chi\in\hat{G}_{d,\pm}$. The uniqueness of $\chi$ is obvious. So we got $\hat{G}_{d,\pm}\cong\hat{P}_{d,\pm}$. Now, as $\hat{P}_d\cong\hat{G}_d$ it follows easily that $|\hat{P}_{d,\pm}|=\frac12\phi(d)$.

Comment: what you wrote is not correct, you didn't count anything except that $\hat{P}_{d,\pm} = \varphi(\hat{G}_{d,\pm})$ which is obvious

Comment: Obvious as it may be, why is it not correct? And as far as I can see, it's a complete prove of my statement.

Answer (score 0):

- There are $\phi(q)$ Dirichlet characters modulo $q$
- If $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $d | q$ then $\tilde{\chi}(n)=\chi(n) 1_{gcd(n,q)=1}$ is a Dirichlet character modulo $q$.
- Let $f(q)$ be the number of primitive Dirichlet characters modulo $q$ then

$$\phi(q) =\sum_{d | q} f(d) \quad \\ \implies \quad f(q) = \sum_{d | q} \mu(d) \phi(q/d) = \prod_{p^k \| q} f(p^k)= \prod_{p^k \| q} (\phi(p^k)-\phi(p^{k-1}))$$

- For $q > 2$ : the map $\{ \chi \bmod q \} \to \{-1,1\}$,  $\chi  \mapsto \chi(-1)$ is a surjective group morphism with kernel the Dirichlet characters with $\chi(-1) = 1$. Thus there are $\phi_1(q) = \frac{\phi(q)}{2}$ Dirichlet characters modulo $q$ with $\chi(-1)= 1$ (excepted the special case $\phi_1(1)= \phi_1(2) =1$).

  Also $\tilde{\chi}(-1) = \chi(-1)$ thus again (with $f_1(q)$ the number of primitive characters modulo $q$ with $\chi(-1)=1$)
  $$\phi_1(q) =\sum_{d |q} f_1(q)  \implies f_1(q) = \sum_{d | q} \mu(d)\phi_1(q/d) = \frac{\mu(q)+\mu(q/2)+f(q)}{2}$$
  and hence $$f_{-1}(q) = f(q)-f_1(q) = \frac{-\mu(q)-\mu(q/2)+f(q)}{2}$$

Comment: I don't see how this proves the statement I was looking for...

Comment: @M.Charbonnier Are you kidding ?

Comment: Sorry, but are you kidding? How many $\chi\in\hat{G}_q$ are there with $f_\chi\mid d\mid q$ (and $\chi(-1)=\pm1$)? All you did (correct my if I'm wrong) is counting the primitive $\chi\in\hat{G}_q$ with $\chi(-1)=\pm1$. So how is that answering my question?

Comment: @M.Charbonnier Your non-question was trivial (the isomorphism $\chi \mapsto \chi 1_{gcd(n,q)=1}$). When asking about primitive Dirichlet characters you are supposed to know that. I answered to the interesting questions : how many characters and primitive characters modulo $q$ and with $\chi(-1) = 1$ or $-1$. Also your argument for obtaining $\phi(d)/2$ is not correct. Don't come on MSE if it is not to learn things.

Comment: I really don't want to start a fight, but the point of my question wasn't the condition $\chi(-1)=\pm1$ but the condition on the conductor of $\chi$ modulo $q$. I'm talking about a different isomorphism than you do, too. Maybe you should just thoroughly read my question and prove again. I came here to learn things, but not things that _you_ consider interesting but I myself.

Comment: And maybe you could just tell me what is wrong with my prove, that I can actually _learn things_.

Comment: @M.Charbonnier What you need to know is in my answer. The isomorphism $\chi \mapsto \chi 1_{gcd(n,q)=1}$ is trivial. 
It follows $\phi(q) = \sum_{d | q} f(d)$ which tells us the number of primitive characters. And we know (for $q > 2$) half of the characters have $\chi(-1) = 1$ because the characters modulo $q$ form an abelian group, with a surjective morphism $\chi \mapsto \chi(-1) \in \{-1,1\}$.

Comment: The surjectivity means there is a character modulo $q$ with $\chi(-1)=-1$, that you need to prove on your side.

Comment: Yeah, this is pointless, case closed. My prove is fine, so I got what I needed. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @M.Charbonnier Is it clear what I wrote in my answer ?

Comment: As I took $\#\hat{P}_d=\#\hat{G}_d$ and $\#\hat{G}_{d,\pm}=\frac12\phi(d)$ for a fact (I already knew the proof of that), I just had to show that $\#\hat{G}_{d,\pm}=\#\hat{P}_{d,\pm}$. So by showing, that my map $\varphi$ from below is bijective, I'm done. And I did show this.